# can = follow by a variable in sql

Tags: sql

I have two tables movie with moive id, movie title, director of the movie, and rating with rating id, movie id, and rating.

The question is to select  director's name together with the title(s) of the movie(s) they directed that received the highest rating among all of their movies, and the value of that rating.

I am trying to understand the following solution

```
  select distinct director, title, stars
  from (movie join rating using (mid)) m
  where stars in (select max(stars) 
            from rating join movie using (mid) 
            where m.director = director)
```

I am in particular confused with the last subquery

```
            select max(stars) 
            from rating join movie using (mid) 
            where m.director = director
```

from all I know, '=' can only be followed by a fixed value, but here it seems to suggest 'looping' through all distinct directors. Which table is the latter director referring to? And how does the looping concept work in sql?

Answer (score 1):

Although this code works to find the highest rated of all movies, it does not do so for each distinct director and it's not the simplest solution, which I will include below. However, the answers to your questions are:

1) The second `director` (from the where clause in the subquery) is referring to the table created in that subquery while the other `m.director` is using the m alias of the first table created in the main query.

2) This isn't really a loop here, in the traditional sense of the word. Basically what the above query is saying is: 'Give me the distinct director name, movie name, and rating from the table created by joining rating to movie, where the number of stars is the largest number of stars pulled from this subquery.' Loops for SQL server use the `WHILE` keyword but they are pretty rare in SQL since there are other functions (or clauses) that can fulfill the same purpose without the need for iteration.

The query posted in your comment only returns a single line with the data for the highest rated movie of all movies in the database not the highest rated movie for each director. The following is a simpler way of writing the query which gives the highest rating achieved for all movies for each director:

`SELECT director, title, MAX(stars)
   FROM movie 
   JOIN rating 
     ON movie.title = rating.movieID
  GROUP BY director`

Comment: Good answer. Can you please clarify the `(mid)` expression. It's not one I'm familiar with.

Comment: I think `(mid)` just stands for 'movie id' I have never used this type of query before. So I am not sure what the OP is using it for. For example, in the sample query I provided, I use the `JOIN`...`ON` clause.

Comment: '......pulled from this subquery', but if I look at this subquery independently it does not make any sense since director is not really a fixed value, which director are we talking about if we view it independently? Also how does your solution deal with the case when the title does not match the max(stars). I am asking this because group by only displays one row for each group, and that one row might not match with max(stars).

Comment: Also, the posted answer does return the correct answer.

Comment: The `WHERE m.director = director` seems to be unnecessary. I think it is similar to saying 'Where the director is in the list of directors'. When I run it on a sample database (mySQL) on my machine the query returns the same value (i.e. max(stars)) regardless of whether I include the WHERE clause or not. The `GROUP BY` clause returns the row matching the aggregate function. In the case of the query I posted, it will return the movie with the most stars for each director, however, if there are two movies with a matching number of stars then it will return the first movie in the table.

Comment: MID is a column in both the movie and rating table.  using is syntax indcating join movie to rating using the mid column (which likely stands for movieID)